# A sequence of $\pm 1$ producing polynomials with real roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, roots

Here is an interesting problem :

> Is there a sequence $(\varepsilon _n)_{n \geqslant 0} \in
> > \{-1,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that for every $N \geqslant 1$, the
>   polynomial $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^N \varepsilon _n X^n$ have $N$ real roots.

The result is true where one search for a **real sequence** $(\varepsilon _n)_{n \geqslant 0}$. In my opinion such a sequence with values $\pm 1$ should not exist, but I am not able to prove it.

Comment: I recently read an article in italian where it is proved that there exists only finitely many polynomials whose coefficients are $\pm 1$ and such that all roots are real, and a complete (quite short) list was given. So, the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Thank you for confirming me that the answer is no. So the only proof you have is to try and list every sequence satisfying the condition for small $N$ ? Can you give me a link to the article ? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's better if I write down the proof in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N \varepsilon_nx^n$$ be a polynomial whose roots $r_1, \dots , r_N$ are all real. WLOG we can suppose $\varepsilon_N = 1$ (i.e. $f$ is monic), and that $N \ge 2$. I will show that $N \le 3$. This will be enough to conclude that your sequence cannot exist.

First, by Vieta's formulas we have
$$0 < \sum_j r_j^2 = (-\varepsilon_{N-1})^2 - 2\varepsilon_{N-2} = 1- 2\varepsilon_{N-2}$$
hence necessarily $\varepsilon_{N-2} = -1$ and $\sum_j r_j^2 = (-\varepsilon_{N-1})^2 = 1-2(-1)=3$.

The second step is to notice that
$$\prod_j r_j^2 = \varepsilon_0^2 = 1$$
Applying the AM-GM inequality to the positive real numbers $r_1^2, \dots , r_N^2$ you get
$$\frac{3}{N}= \frac{1}{N} \sum_j r_j^2 \ge \sqrt[N]{\prod_j r_j^2} = 1$$
so that $N \le 3$.

Comment: This is a nice method !